# Add number of items as a class to menus

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to add a class to menu that shows how many items are in that particular level.  I.E.

```
<ul class="menu count-5">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

What's the best way to do this?

I've looked at [theme_menu_tree](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_tree/7) but the tree is already rendered html by that point so there is no easy way to count the number of items.

Answer (score 2):

It really feels like there should be a better way to do this (but I can't find one at the moment, `theme_menu_link()` isn't context-aware of its parent menu); however this will work:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_tree(&$variables) {
  // Load the current HTML into a DOMDocument to count the links
  $doc = new DOMDocument;
  $doc->loadHTML('<ul class="identifiable-string">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>');

  // XPath query to find only top-level <li>s
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
  $lis = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="identifiable-string"]/li');

  // Get the count based on the number of elements returned
  $count = 0;
  if ($lis) {
    foreach ($lis as $li) {
      $count++;
    }
  }

  return '<ul class="menu count-' . $count . '">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

It seems like a huge amount of effort (not to mention processor power) for not much reward, but if you're struggling then this method will definitely work.

Comment: This definitely looks like the most reliable PHP solution, but considering the roadblocks thrown up by Drupal in this situation, I'd highly recommend that OP reconsider his aversion to using jQuery for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to do that with jQuery.

```
var num_links = jQuery('.menu > li').length;
jQuery('.menu').addClass('count-'+num_links);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  Thanks for the thought though

Answer (score 0):

The API function you want is [theme_menu_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7). The information about each menu link's child menu items is available in this function. You will need to count the child menu items and use that count as part of your class. However, the array that holds the child menu items also holds other information.

The following implementation of theme_menu_link() worked for me with a quick, superficial test:

```
function THEMENAME_menu_link(array $variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $sub_menu = '';

  if ($element['#below']) {
    $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    $count = 0;
    foreach($element['#below'] as $key=>$item) {
      //the child menu items' keys are their mlid, which is numeric
      //most other items in this array will not have numeric keys
      if(is_numeric($key)) {
        $count ++;
      }
    }
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'count-'.$count;
  }
  $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Comment: I just realized I misunderstood the question, so my answer is irrelevant. But still maybe helpful for someone? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use theme_menu_tree(), just [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the tree into an array.

Something like this should work:

```
function THEMENAME_menu_tree($variables) {
$menu_items = explode('</li>', trim($variables['tree']));
$count = count($menu_items);

  return '<ul class="menu count-'.$count.'">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I don't think this will work for menus that have multiple levels. The split on `</li>` would produce some very unpredictable results

Comment: You're right. I meant to add that disclaimer to my answer.  You could explode on '</ul>' and then explode the resulting strings on '</li>', but yeah, it gets very messy.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176013/how-can-count-the-children-of-drupals-main-menu

it is possible to use [menu_tree_page_data](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_page_data/7).

You could thus use this in combination with `theme_menu_tree`, for instance:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_tree(&$variables) {
  $count = count(menu_tree_page_data('main-menu'));
  return '<ul class="menu count-' . $count . '">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Please note that this will trigger for every single menu that displays in your page and it will always return the number of items of the menu 'main-menu'.

If you want to tailor it to a specific menu, you'd have to implement `THEMENAME_menu_tree__MENU_NAME()` in order to override the function for a specific menu.